# How to cancel fmt.Scanf after a certain timeout?

Tags: go

I have a very simple command line utility and at the end of it I'm waiting for a user to hit the enter key to end the program:

```
fmt.Scanf("\n") // wait for hitting the enter key to end the program
```

Now I want to change it and if the enter key hasn't been hit for some time, I want to cancel `Scanf` and do something else. Is it possible to cancel waiting for user's input?

Comment: See https://gobyexample.com/timeouts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply create a channel and launch a goroutine which does the `fmt.Scanf("\n")` and then writes something to the channel. Then `select` between that channel and `time.After(3 * time.Second)`.

Here's a solution:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Rest of the program...

    ch := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        fmt.Scanf("\n")
        ch <- 1
    }()

    select {
    case <-ch:
        fmt.Println("Exiting.")
        os.Exit(0)
    case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("Timed out, exiting.")
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: as pointed out by @Fabian and @YotKay in the comments, this will "leak" a goroutine (meaning it will remain running until the process exits) if the timeout expires and the user does not enter anything. This is still fine in a situation in which you have to either wait for input or exit the program, but not advisable in other cases, since it's not possible to "cancel" goroutines from the outside.

Comment: just to be clear, there is absolutely no way to do this without goroutines, right?

Comment: @vitr nope, there isn't. There may be some more concise way perhaps using some libraries, but internally it all has to happen with two different goroutines: one waiting for input and one waiting for a certain amount of time to pass, since waiting for user input is a blocking action.

Comment: Though the goroutine will keep existing while no line was entered yet.

Comment: This will leak the goroutine and also block reading from Stdin. Try adding one more read after this timeout (after whole select statement), and you'll see a strange thing happens: what you write is first consumed by the Scanf in the goroutine. You'll have to enter text again to be consumed by your second Scanf.

Comment: @YotKay you're right, the goroutine is leaked if the 3s timeout runs out. How would you suggest getting around that?

Comment: Seems like there is no perfect solution in Go for this. Please take a look at this post, it is very good: https://benjamincongdon.me/blog/2020/04/23/Cancelable-Reads-in-Go/

Answer (score 6):

You just need to put it in an infinate loop

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "context"
)

// 3 seconds for example
var deadline = time.Second * 3

func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 1)
    go scan(c)

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), deadline)

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        // didnt type for deadline seconds
    case <-c:
        // did it in time
    }
}

func scan(in chan string) {
    var input string
    _, err := fmt.Scanln(&input)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    in <- input
}
```